# How can I use two versions of libsqilite 3 in linux?

Tags: linux, sqlite, mono, qnap, duplicati

I posted this question a while ago in the qnap forum but had no answer (http://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?p=480557&sid=8bb86fda3f81fff50c82dc0e74810188), so I decided to post it here also.

On my customers QNAP boxes, I have an old version of the sqlite3 library, /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6, but for software like duplicati backup, I need a higher version. I compiled sqlite amalgamation version 3080704 successfully on the box.

Is it enough to copy the compiled .so lib in /usr/lib to allow duplicati to use the good one (duplicati complains about an old version of the library if I use the builtin).

Duplicati is (L)GPL software written in C# (.NET) that runs just fine in MONO, but I guess I can't compile it to include the sqlite3 library statically.

Does anyone have a similar issue with lib versions, and may be a possible solution ?

Cheers, Francesco.

Answer (score 0):

The solution lies in linux mono's "DllMaps", and it is documented in the article I posted in the qnap forum (see link in question).